# php sms code error

Tags: php, cakephp

I am try to php coding for  registering our products  after confirm sms alert posting in our mobile number ....in using way2 sms mobile site ..it seems some error occured ....

Message has been sent your email address Logging in ... 
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\html\class.sms.php on line 126
Sending SMS ... 
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\html\class.sms.php on line 147
Error encountered :

```
class.sms.php :


preg_match($pattern,$out,$matches);
        $id=trim($matches[1]);     // 126 line
        $this->data['id']=$id;

    }

    private function send_160by2($number,$msg)
    {
        $msg=urlencode($msg);
        $id=$this->data['id'];
        $out1=$this->curl->post("http://m.160by2.com/...Compose.asp?l=1","txt_mobileno=$number&txt_msg=$msg&cmdSend=Send+SMS&TID=&T_MsgId=&Msg=$id");
        //echo $out1;
        $pattern = '/\<table.+?\>(.+)\<\/table/s';
        preg_match($pattern, $out1, $matches);

        $out=strip_tags(@$matches[1]);
        if(count($matches)<1)
        {
        $pattern="/\<div.+?background:.+?yellow.+?\>(.+?)\<\/div\>/s";

        preg_match($pattern,$out1,$matches);

        $out=strip_tags($matches[1]);           // 147 line 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The message looks pretty clear to me: `$matches[1]` does not have an element at position `1`.
Try printing your `$matches` array like this and you'll see what you have:

```
preg_match($pattern,$out,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Looks like your RegEx is not returning any resulting `$matches`.

Comment: dude i cause an error:Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\html\class.sms.php on line 126
Sending SMS ... Array ( ) Error encountered :

Comment: Looks like your `$pattern` cannot find any `$matches` in your `$out` string. Can you print them and paste them in the comment?